Is it impossible to use classes from src folder in Jenkins Shared Library in a Declarative Pipeline?
According to the Jenkins docs, we have the following:
The src directory should look like standard Java source directory structure. This directory is added to the classpath when executing Pipelines.
This makes me believe that it should be somehow possible to import classes from the Shared Library and use them in the Pipeline. I want to use them WITHOUT script blocks, the same way I would use functions I defined in the vars folder.
So ultimately, suppose I have this:
jenkins-shared-lib/src/org/foo/MyCls.groovy
package org.foo

class MyCls {
    def func1() {
        println "Hello"
    }
}

I want to be able to call it in the Declarative Pipeline somehow without using Script blocks.
This works:
@Library('shared-library') _
import org.foo.MyCls
def x = new MyCls()

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {              
                script {
                    x.func1()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

But is it not possible to omit the script block and use it similarly to how functions defined in vars are being used? If not, could you explain why and where in the docs they mention this explicitly? Because the docs made it seem like both src and vars are possible but from what I understand, vars works for Declarative Pipeline and hence most people have their functions in vars and src might work nicely for Scripted Pipeline. For Declarative, I'd thus need to use the script blocks...
I looked into the Docs, at example repos, at StackOverflow / Reddit posts but none of them seem to do what I want to do, so I want a definite answer if this is possible or not and also why.
The only example I found where it seemed like it would work is this one here, but the Repo is gone and it's unclear if the guy was using a declarative or scripted pipeline: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Jenkins-Shared-Library-GitHub-Example-Pipeline

Yes you can use both class methods and global variable methods in a declarative pipeline. No you cannot invoke them outside of a script block unless it is a custom step: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps

Generally speaking you can't omit the script block for the functions defined in vars either.
If you have a util.groovy file in vars that defines a customGreeting() function you cannot do
steps{
    util.customGreeting()
}

There are some specific cases when you can call them without the script block

Your var file has a call() function and you are using it as a step
Calling a function inside an expression, like

echo util.customGreeting()

The latter can be used with classes defined in src as well, but classes from src are not added to steps, so the former doesn't work.
